# Cannot transform T4 templates on VS2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, t4

I've been able to transform T4 templates, both on VS2015 and VS2017, until I replaced my failing computer and installed ***only*** VS2017 on the new device.

I always get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       An exception was thrown while trying to compile the transformation code. The following Exception was thrown:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell'.
>   File name: 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell'
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>      at Roslyn.Utilities.FileUtilities.OpenFileStream(String path)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(String path, MetadataReferenceProperties properties, DocumentationProvider documentation)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.<>c.<.ctor>b__15_0(String x)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<UnionIterator>d__67`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__67`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray.CreateRange[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ImmutableArrayExtensions.AsImmutableOrEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 items)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.ValidateReferences[T](IEnumerable`1 references)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.WithReferences(IEnumerable`1 references)
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.CommonWithReferences(IEnumerable`1 newReferences)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.PrepareNewCompilation()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.CompilerBridge.Compile()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TransformationRunner.Compile(String source, String inputFile, IEnumerable`1 references, Boolean debug, SupportedLanguage language, String compilerOptions)          1

I've the "Text Template Transformation" enabled in Visual Studio installer.

I tried copying the DLL  from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies` to `system32` with no luck.

I also tried registering the DLL with `gacutil -i` with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: FileNotFoundException can happen for missing dependencies, or when a constructor for static object throws. First is IMO more likely.  For the first, use e.g. sysinternals process monitor, it will show you which DLL wasn’t found. For the second, run the command-line transform tool with debugger attached, the tool is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\14.0\TextTransform.exe`, set up to break on C++ & SEH exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that one of my templates was referencing `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell`.

But VS2017 only ships with a newer version called `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0`.

After changing the reference in the .tt the issue went away.

Comment: I was also able to solve this problem by installing the VS 2015 isolated shell, which I downloaded from Microsoft:  https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/